# K8s ingress + Apache - CORS errors

Tags: cors, kubernetes-ingress

Trying to move my services into K8s. I am using Apache + PHP in my docker containers, it is easiest way for me to try to move application to K8s and start to test it.

So, my current WEB structure is: WEB -> K8s Nginx Ingress -> Apache -> PHP

My application is using subdomains:

```
a.example.com
b.example.com
c.example.com
```

So, during testing I am starting from opening `a.example.com`. The site is opening without errors. After that, during navigation, I am redirecting to `b.example.com` - and there is no errors too. But when I redirecting to `c.example.com` - I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'a.example.com/test.xml' from origin 
'https://c.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 
'https://b.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

When I am checking Response headers, I for some reason I see:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://b.example.com (it should be c.example.com)
```

If I will wait 3 - 4 minutes and redirect page - error is missing. So, this behavior is like a some cache.

My K8s ingress controller has this config:

```
...
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://*.example.com" 
...
```

And, again, when I am going back to `b.example.com` - I am starting to get the same error, but for this time I get

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://c.example.com (it should be b.example.com)
```

And CORS error is related to `c.example.com`. And the same behavior with time - if I will wait for 3 - 4 minutes and refresh the page - it is starting to work as expected.

Is it cache related issue? And why it is happening if I have `"https://*.example.com"` enabled in Ingress? What should I check?

UPDATE:

It is possible that maybe I found solution, I am currently testing it. For apache config of `a.example.com` I added this line:

```
...
<Files "test.xml">
  Header always set Vary Origin <------ this helped me, all below was before
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
  Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, accept"
</Files>
...
```

So, I still have a lot of questions. What does mean `Header always set Vary Origin`, why my K8s nginx ingress `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://*.example.com"`  was ignored?